# handling join table in springboot for mysql

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, jpa, one-to-many

I want to build a api with result that contain a order entity with attribute of a
list of productMap (which is a map of ordered products with Product as key and value as the number of product)The api will also expected displayed to whole product entity correspond to the map .Order is One to Many to product.My latest approach for it is to build a new table ProductMap for storing the one to many relationship.

Here is the code for entity of order:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "Order_table")
public class Order {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private UUID OrderId;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "op_fk")
    private List<ProductMap> productsMap_key;



    private double amount;

    private LocalDate date;

    private LocalDate dueDate;

    @OneToOne @MapsId
    private Invoice invoice;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Customer.class,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "oi_fk",referencedColumnName = "CustomerId")
    private Customer customer;


}
```

The product:

```
Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@Table
@Builder
public class Product {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private UUID ProductId;

    private String ProductName;

    private double price;

    private int storage;



}
```

The productMap entity:

```
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@Table
@Builder
public class ProductMap {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private UUID ProductMapId;

    private UUID OrderId;

    private UUID ProductId;

    private int quantity;
}
```

Is there any better approach for this problem since it is actually quiet complicated and not straight-forward for implmenting join table relations    , i have think of adding the true query directly or seperate the sql the serveral small function and group them by function but as i know that using join table directly in sql in not recommended .